# Tampermonkey script failing to amend form controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tampermonkey

I am making a script for a betting website to Automate it but my script is not working.

I want to auto click the buttons with IDs `#box38`, `#playBtn`, `#resetStats`. I also want that when I lose, increase the bet to `0.00000004` and when I win,  reset it to `0.00000001` but that is not working either and I don't know why.

There is 2 text with IDs `#currentWins` and `#currentLossess`. Why is that not working?

I just want these to work:

- click buttons without a problem
- increase/decrease bet without a problem

The code is just not working at all. I'm also using TamperMonkey and I haven't forgotten to add the latest version of jQuery

HTML:

three buttons:

```
<a id="resetStats">RESET</a>
<div class="box" id="box38" onclick="Game.play(38); return false;"></div>
<button class="btn blue" id="playBtn" onclick="Game.play(0); >LET'S GO!</button>
```

and 2 text written in div tags:

```
<div class="input green" id="currentWins">0</div>
<div class="input red" id="currentLosses">0</div>
```

```js
function doit() {
  window.setInterval(event1, 2000);

  $("#playBtn").click();

  function event1() {
    $("#box38").click();

    (function() {
      $("#resetStats").click();
      $("#playBtn").click();
      setTimeout(arguments.callee, 5000);
    })();
  }

  function winloss() {
    var wins = $("div#currentWins").text();
    var loss = $("div#currentLosses").text();
    if (wins == 1) {
      document.getElementById("betAmount").value = "0.00000001";
      doit();
    } else if (loss == 1) {
      document.getElementById("betAmount").value = "0.00000004";
      doit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why downvote? just tell me where im wrong

Comment: Firstly we can't really help without seeing the HTML. Secondly `=` is for value assignment, `==` is for comparison. As such all your `if` statements need to be changed to use `==`. Also note that `text()` returns a string, so comparing it to an integer may cause issues

Comment: `why use == for if statement?` because that's how Javascript syntax works.

Comment: code edited and its not working... what's the problem?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i used = it was working fine with == it's working too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, I found out that there were multiple problems.

- `doit` was never called.
- `winloss` was never called.
- You called `doit` after finishing `winloss`, even though, looking at your code, you intended to click `#box38` once.
- You called `$("#playBtn").click` even though it was already automatically looped in the `event1` private function.
- In the HTML you gave, there wasn't a `#betAmount` with the `value` property.
- In the HTML you gave, `#resetStats` as an `<a>`, but it's most probably a button.

So hopefully I read your code and question correctly, and I refactored it:

```js
function doit() {
  event1()

  function event1() {
    $("#box38").click();
    winloss();
    (function() {

      winloss()
      $("#resetStats").click();
      $("#playBtn").click();
      setTimeout(arguments.callee, 5000);

    })();
  }

  function winloss() {
    const lost = $("div#currentLosses").text() != 0
    if (lost) {
      document.getElementById("betAmount").value = "0.00000004";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("betAmount").value = "0.00000001";
    }
  }

}
doit()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="resetStats" onclick="$('div#currentWins').text(0);$('div#currentLosses').text(0)">RESET</button>
<script>
  let Game = {
    play: function(a) {
      if (a == 38) {
        return false
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        let wins = $("div#currentWins").text()
        let losses = $("div#currentLosses").text()
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
          wins++
        } else {
          losses++
        }
        $("div#currentWins").text(wins)
        $("div#currentLosses").text(losses)
      }, 4000) //Simulating API delay
    }
  }
</script>
<div class="box" id="box38" onclick="Game.play(38); return false;"></div>
<button class="btn blue" id="playBtn" onclick="Game.play(0);">LET'S GO!</button>
<div class="input green" id="currentWins">0</div>
<div class="input red" id="currentLosses">0</div>
<input id="betAmount" value="0">
```

Comment: Thank you so much it will help me alot :)